# Best way to read INI file updating every 5 seconds with duplicate sections

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to monitor a machine at work and i have an INI file that updates its data at every machine state(5 seconds or so) with VB.net

what i'm trying to do is select only the last written data

i tried to watch the file with a systemfilewatcher but i get the whole text ( i can select data by date but the date value is after the section name)

is there a way to select only the written data after the last ini read ?

Thanks in advance.

here's a sample of my ini file

> Blockquote

```
[SampleStarted]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:48:44
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido
PressSingleCycleActivated=1
SampleRequestedPieces=3

[SampleTerminated]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:48:55
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido
SampleRequestedPieces=3

[LearnStarted]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:49:15
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido
PressSingleCycleActivated=1

[LearnTerminated]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:50:09
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido

[ProductionStarted]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:55:56
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido
PressSingleCycleActivated=1
ProductionRequestedPieces=1850
UserRequestedPieces=0
TotalGoodPieces=0
ProductionPieces=0, 0
ProductionIncompletePieces=0

[ProductionInterrupted]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:56:21
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido
ProductionRequestedPieces=1850
UserRequestedPieces=0
TotalGoodPieces=7
ProductionPieces=7, 7
ProductionIncompletePieces=0

[ProductionRestarted]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:58:20
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido
PressSingleCycleActivated=1
ProductionRequestedPieces=1850
UserRequestedPieces=0
TotalGoodPieces=7
ProductionPieces=7, 7
ProductionIncompletePieces=0

[ProductionInterrupted]
DateTimeStamp=09/10/2017,15:58:40
ArticleKey=M17041_F374001
Job=HC51354811, 1
UserName=mido
ProductionRequestedPieces=1850
UserRequestedPieces=0
TotalGoodPieces=12
ProductionPieces=12, 12
ProductionIncompletePieces=0
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i am currently using a filewatcher to watch the inifile with the code below

    Dim ini As New IniFile()
    ini.Load("D:\machinestate.ini")
    ProductionState  = "ProductionStarted"
    DatetimeStamp  =Cdate( ini.Sections("ProductionStarted").Keys("DateTimeStamp").Value)
    Article = ini.Sections("ProductionStarted").Keys("ArticleKey").Value

comment doesn't allow me to put whole code 
i'm using MadMilkman API with a systemfilewatcher to watch the INI file

Comment: Use a file watcher to detect when the file has changed, but keep track of the previous file size.  If it was, for example 1000 bytes before and now it's 1500, seek to the place you left off before reading.  Also, if new size is smaller, assume file was deleted and start at the beginning.

Comment: Sadly there is no way to directly be notified of what has changed within the file. Youd would need to keep an in memory copy of the last version INI file and compare it with the file on disk and dealing with any changes. If there are changes update the in memory copy with the changed file, and so on.

Comment: thanks Dwiliss and Wilson,
do you have any example of that in VB.net ?